# Windows 10 Explorer file open dialog: filenames disappearing in compiled executable

Tags: python, winapi, wxpython, explorer, openfiledialog

We have a sizeable, legacy Python application written in Python 2.7 64 bit on Windows 10 64 bit - with GUI in wxPython, heavy numerical computations via NumPy, 2D plotting with MatPlotLib, 3D with VTK and so on, which we distribute as py2exe compiled binary after converting all our own Python files to pyd (Windows dlls) using Cython.

Since about a month ago, we started experiencing a super weird behavior of the file open dialog on Windows - i.e., a dialog that appears when the user asks to load a model/file from disk. The issue is, all the filenames are gone, we can only see the icons for folders/files, no text at all.

Please see picture below:

[image]

As you can see, the central list which usually contains icons and filenames now displays only icons. The only way to get the filenames back is to right-click in the main window and select "Refresh" - although sometimes navigating to a different folder makes the filenames show up.

This behavior does not show up while using the Python code, only in the compiled app. And it does not happen with other software (Microsoft Office, Notepad++, anything else, they all use the native Windows file dialog like our app and they all work all right).

I have been fighting with this for days and days, and it's not that obvious what is going on as the executable distribution folder has hundreds of dlls and standard Python modules and sub-folders containing the Python standard library plus all 3rd party libraries... the possible interactions between those dlls and Windows native ones are uncountable.

We also have zero control on Windows updates, when and where and how, and zero access privileges on our machines as they are locked down corporate beasts.

Now, for the questions:

1. Has anybody ever seen this behavior before in an app? If yes, can you point us to a possible solution?
2. If no one has seen this before, do you know if there is a way to force a refresh of an open file dialog, by whatever mean necessary - whether it is a MFC command, a Python one via win32gui, a system call, a C hack, anything?

Thank you in advance from a hair-pulling fellow programmer.

**EDIT**

After some more pain, I found out that py2exe had included a Windows DLL (PROPSYS.dll) from my machine, which was incompatible with all other machines (they have all sort of architectures). Excluding that DLL from the build system has fixed the problem.

Thanks go to @Simon Mourier for the invaluable suggestion to look at the DLL used by the process. Thank you!!! If you post your comment as an answer I’ll accept it as solution.

Comment: Are you displaying real files or are they items in some virtual folder? Is it doing that for any folder? If they are real files and it does that for any folder, it probably means the Windows process hosting the Common Dialog corrupts its memory in some way.

Comment: They are real files and real folders, no virtual stuff. It happens in both local files (on the pc hard drive) and on network disks. In general it does that for any folder - although I haven’t tried all of them - with some exceptions: navigating to another folder sometimes make the list all visible, sometimes not. The only robust solution is to right-click and select “Refresh” - hardly a user-friendly solution though...

Comment: One thing you can try is check what are the .dll in your process, check any 3rd party (hosting Common Dialog can bring in many Shell extensions). But why would it work for other apps? IMHO, it smells like a bug in the tooling that you use, probably around memory management. What you could do is start with a minimal process using common dialog and add more and more, see when it start breaking. ie: is there any simple way to reproduce this?

Comment: The application is kind of big, written in high level language (Python), so it’s unlikely I’ll be able to build piece by piece. Not much has changed since last month - when everything was working fine, except we added a very small module that uses CEFPython (Chromium) to handle interactions between our app and a chrome browser. But that module is only imported when the user clicks on a specific button, not at runtime. And nothing has changed in the building tools. We got some Windows updates. I’ll try with your suggestion to check what dll are loaded by our app, I’m desperate. Thank you.

Comment: CEF in itself is far from being small. Try to see if it works when you remove that new module(s). I bet this has nothing to do with Windows itself.

Comment: Simon please see the edit, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, when an application fails in a strange way, one idea is to check what are the .dll loaded in that application's process and try to spot anything that looks strange.

This is especially true when you use the Common Dialog (Open, Save As) provider by the Windows Shell since doing that potentially bring in a lot of 3rd parties .dll, loading them in the process.

One of the best tool to check that is [Process Explorer from Sysinternals.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Here is a screenshot that shows external .dll opened in standard Notepad just because I used the File Open dialog box. We can see Intel's extensions, Adobe extensions, OneDrive, etc.

[image]

It was not the issue here, but still, it apparently helped spot the problem.